# What t is the difference between "Context" and "TestRunner" in SOAPUI?

Tags: groovy, soapui

While writing groovy in SOAPUI some times we use context and some times we use TestRunner,

Need help to understand the difference.

Answer (score 11):

From the [documentation](http://www.soapui.org/Functional-Testing/working-with-scripts.html):

- [testRunner](http://www.soapui.org/apidocs/index.html?com/eviware/soapui/model/testsuite/TestRunner.html) - a TestCaseRunner object, which is the
  entry-point to the soapUI API for accessing project items, results,
  etc. The testRunner is the object that is actually executing the
  TestCase by cycling through the TestSteps in the TestCase and
  executing them. It exposes methods related to test execution and the
  underlying object model (via the testCase property). Common usage
  scenarios are:

  - using testRunner.testCase to get hold of the containing TestCase from which all other objects in the project can be accessed and manipulated
  - using testRunner.fail(...) (or testRunner.cancel) to abort the ongoing TestCase when an error occurs
  - using testRunner.gotoStepByName(...) or testRunning.runTestStepByName( ... ) to transfer execution to another step than the one after the Script TestStep in the TestCase (see ...)
- [context](http://www.soapui.org/apidocs/index.html?com/eviware/soapui/impl/wadl/inference/schema/Context.html) - a TestCaseRunContext object holding    context-related
  properties. The main usage for this is to store    values that can be
  used in subsequent TestSteps or related scripts.    For example

  context.myProperty = "Hello"

  will create a property named "myProperty" in the context and assign
  it the string value "Hello". In a subsequent script, you can access
  it with

  log.info( context.myProperty )